# System.StringException: Invalid id: j_id0:mainFrm

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am receiving the Exception

> "**System.StringException: Invalid id: j_id0:mainFrm**".
>
> Visualforce Page: /apex/ReasonCode
>   Class.ReasonCodeController.requestCodes: line 10, column 1

```
public PageReference createNewCust()
{       customer.field__c = null;
    insert customer;
    PageReference CaseDetails = new PageReference('/apex/ReasonCode?ccid='+customer.Id+'&retUrl=/'+customer.url__c);
    CaseDetails.setRedirect(false); 
    return CaseDetails;
}  





public PageReference requestCodes() 
{
        String ccId;
        Object__c currId ;
        disableButton = true;
        currId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        retURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
        ccId =   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ccid');               
        currIR = [select  field_2__c, field_3__c, field_4__c, field_5__c, field_6__c, field_7__c FROM Object__c where id=:currId ];

        system.debug('requestCodes requested..');

        currIR = new Object__c ();
        currIR.field_2__c = lkId;
        upsert currIR;
        return new PageReference(retURL);

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Object__c" extensions="requestCodeController"     action="{!doLoad}" readOnly="false">
       <apex:form id="mainFrm">
      <script>
      function disableButton(btnId)
      {
      btnId.disabled=true;
      dsbleBtn();
      }
      </script>
       <center>
        <apex:actionStatus stopText="" id="refreshstatus">
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <img src="{!$Resource.waitingimg}" />
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </center>
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <br/> <br/>
        <apex:pageBlock id="commentPB" mode="maindetail" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="commentPBS">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Customer Comments :   " for="commentOT" 

    style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial"/>
               <apex:outputText id="commentOT" value="{!customerComment}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
           </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlock id="pb" mode="maindetail" >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:actionFunction name="dsbleBtn" action="{!requestCodes}" status="refreshstatus" reRender="mainFrm"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save"  onclick="disableButton(this)"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancelReason}" immediate="true"/>
                   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Going through different Blogs and sites, I found Generally this **exception arises if the Id value is Invalid and is thrown by Apex Class** but in my case The **Invalid Id** Value is from The Apex Page.
Does the exception arise from Apex page..?

Comment: Can you post your page code as well? Make sure you don't have same `id` for multiple elements

Comment: is the parameter of "id" that you are passing, a real record id for the same type of Sobject you are using your standardcontroller against?

Comment: Yes, The Id is the Real Record Id assigned to **ccid** after the **customer** record is inserted.

Comment: @highfive,The apex page has on one id(mainFrm)

Comment: Problem I think is, you are using the param Id, but think of it as a reserved param. If you are using it to pass another sobject's Id and it's not the one specified as your standard controller, you can get the error in which you are getting. Can you try and change your param Id to something else and see if that stops giving you errors?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Currently, the issue arises because you are trying to query an object with a selector Id in the filter? What is your question?

Comment: j_id0 is the Apex:Page Id, Assign an Id to the Apex:Page then any calls for your 'mainFrm' just add the apex page Id as well, It probably a hidden div somewhere, If you debug though the VF page inspecting your elements you will find it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the ID variables

> currId, ccId

as String variables and write the values to debug log. You might be trying to assign an null or a invalid string to an ID variable which it throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry For Not Adding but the variable Ccid is declared as String..

Comment: did you print the value for CCid to debug log and checked it? Also just add the page url here to have a look.